# PLEASE help me make this drop down menu work properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drop-down-menu

okay so I've asked a similar question like this before but the answer that I got was so complex that even after 2 hours of trying to integrate it into a laravel website it didn't work. Now I know this seems very lengthy but it really isn't. I just have a problem with expressing myself in few words.

I would really appreciate it if someone could PLEASE help me to fix this (please see the fiddle): http://jsfiddle.net/pyrot/NaE43/ so that it works properly (I've mentioned the issues below).

Currently I used what  pathetic knowledge of jquery I had to hack that together now if someone could just help me to get it to function properly, while still being simply that would be very much appreciated.

I was trying to give it a cool slide down transition when someone hovers over the "view more" link that slides down with these links: "Ads, Sell, Join" and also whenever someone hovers over any of those three links (please hover over the "Ads" link in the fiddle) another drop down box should appear but this time to the right with a slide open transition. I am also struggling with how to make the drop down not disappear when I move the mouse from the "view more" link. I horridly did this for the first drop down box by placing its margin unprofessionally close to the "view more" link and as for the second drop down box (to the right) when I try to go to it, it vanishes like a magic act. I've honestly spent a lot of time on this, but I just can't get it to work. PLEASE HELP ME SOMEONE!

This is my navigation:

```
<ul id="parent-ul">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">brands</a></li>

    <li><a href="#" class="view-drop">view more</a>        
        <span class="view-drop-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="v-d-link-one">Ads</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="v-d-link-two">sell</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="v-d-link-three">Join</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>

        <span class="view-drop-content-two">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        </li>

        <li><a href="#">LINK 4</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">LINK 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

this is my code:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".view-drop, .view-drop-content").hover(function(){
         $('.view-drop-content').show();
    }, function(){
           $('.view-drop-content').hide();
    }) ;

 });

$(document).ready(function() {

    $(".v-d-link-one, .view-drop-content-two").hover(function(){
         $('.view-drop-content-two').show();
    }, function(){
           $('.view-drop-content-two').hide();
    }) ;

 });
```

and this is my css:

```
#parent-ul li {
    display: inline !important;
    list-style-type:none !important;
    padding-right: 5px
}

.view-drop-content {

    display: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px auto 0px -65px;
    z-index: 10;
    float: left;
    border: 4px #84ca40 solid;
    border: 2px #84ca40 solid !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px !important;
    text-indent: -30px;

}

.view-drop-content-two {

    display: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px auto 0px 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    float: right;
    border: 4px #84ca40 solid;
    border: 2px #84ca40 solid !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px !important;
    text-indent: -30px;

}

.view-drop-content > ul li a,
.view-drop-content-two > ul li a {

    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
```

Comment: Instaed try `MouseEnter/MouseLeave/MouseOver` events.

Comment: I tried using that about four (4) hours ago but more issues showed up on my doorstep. Thanks for your reply by the way Ankur140290.

Comment: You should specify the “similar question” so that we can check its answer and see whether this is really a duplicate. And shouting PLEASE repeatedly does not really help.

Answer (score 2):

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".view-drop").hover(function(){
     $('.view-drop-content').slideDown().delay( 800 );

}, function(){
       $('.view-drop-content').slideUp().delay( 800 );
}) ;

$(".view-drop-content ul li").hover(function(){
    $('.view-drop-content').css("display","inline");            
     $('.view-drop-content-two').slideDown().delay( 400 );

}, function(){
       $('.view-drop-content-two').slideUp().delay( 400 );
}) ;




 })

</script>
<style type="text/css">
#parent-ul li {
    display: inline !important;
    list-style-type:none !important;
    padding-right: 5px
}

.view-drop-content {

    display: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 20px auto 0px -65px;
    z-index: 10;
    float: left;
    border: 4px #84ca40 solid;
    border: 2px #84ca40 solid !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px !important;
    text-indent: -30px;

}

.view-drop-content-two {

    display: none;
    background-color: #000000;
    width: auto;
    height: auto;
    position: absolute;
    margin: 15px auto 0px 0px;
    z-index: 10;
    float: right;
    border: 4px #84ca40 solid;
    border: 2px #84ca40 solid !important;
    border-radius: 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
    padding: 0px !important;
    text-indent: -30px;

}

.view-drop-content > ul li a,
.view-drop-content-two > ul li a {

    color: #ffffff;
    display: block;
    text-align: left;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;

}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<ul id="parent-ul">
    <li><a href="#">home<a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about<a></li>
    <li><a href="#">brands<a></li>

    <li class="view-drop"><a href="#" >view more</a>        
        <span class="view-drop-content">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" class="v-d-link">Ads</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="v-d-link">sell</a></li>
                <li><a href="#" class="v-d-link">Join</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>

        <span class="view-drop-content-two">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
            </ul>
        </span>
        </li>

<li><a href="#">LINK 4<a></li>
<li><a href="#">LINK 5<a></li>
</ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Okay Rakesh Godhala, thanks for your response but when I do that it keeps on animating without stopping.

Comment: You need to adjust the css properly.

Comment: Adding delay will delay number of jquery events triggered. so, this will reduce number of sideup and slideDown events in that time interval

Comment: By properly you mean making it so that there are no margins separating the drop down boxes right? but in the one that I would like to get some help with there will be a little bit of margin separating the drop down boxes.

Comment: Okay. Adding a delay would be really smart. thanks. Hey Rakesh Godhala, is this thing incapable of being fixed in the manner that I would like? You see because it came from the murky depths of my untrained mind I am wondering if it's just a lost cause.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44926/discussion-between-rakesh-godhala-and-user3140116)

Answer (score 1):

Try this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/yashhy/NR8AE/2/)**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".view-drop, .view-drop-content").mouseover(function () {
        $('.view-drop-content').show();
    });
    $(".view-drop-content-two, .v-d-link-one").mouseover(function () {
        $('.view-drop-content').show();
        $('.view-drop-content-two').show();
    });
    $(".view-drop-content-two").mouseleave(function () {
        $('.view-drop-content').hide();
        $('.view-drop-content-two').hide();
    });
    $(".view-drop, .view-drop-content").mouseleave(function () {
        $('.view-drop-content').hide();
        $('.view-drop-content-two').hide();
    });
});
```

A small change is made in your HTML `<span>` tag :
I added  `style="margin-left:-2%;"` for the class `view-drop-content-two`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to help me out yashhy but that sort of works the same as my fiddle.

Comment: is it so? @user3140116 it works great in mine, I checked with Chrome and Mozi

Comment: and not that I changed `style="margin-left:-2%;"` for class `view-drop-content-two`

Comment: Well it is showing better now. Checked it in firefox, however you did the same thing I did my making sure that the margins are really close that way they won't disappear when you move from the link that initiated the whole drop down. I was really looking for something that would stay on display even when I move the mouse away from the link that starts the drop down process.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple tutorial for creating CSS Drop down menu

[TUTORIAL](http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-pure-css-dropdown-menu)

Comment: Rahul G Nair, thanks, I've bookmarked that link but I was really hoping for some help with this. Now I don't mean to sound ungrateful or anything. I would just really like to get some help with fixing the script in the jsfiddle.

Answer (score 0):

I think, you can achieve it just in CSS only, You need to change your markup a bit and css ofcourse. Here is the demo:

**HTML:**

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">brands</a></li>        
    <li>
        <a href="#">VIEW MORE</a>        
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Ads</a>
                <ul>
                    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">sell</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Join</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">link 4</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 5</a></li>
</ul>
```

**CSS:**

```
*{margin:0; padding:0}
#menu > li {
    float:left;
    list-style-type:none;
    padding-right: 5px;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
}

#menu li ul{
    display:none;
    background:#000;
    border: 1px #84ca40 solid;
    position:absolute;
    top:20px;
    left:0;
    width:80px;
}
#menu li:hover > ul{
    display:block;
}
#menu li li ul{
    padding:0;
    top:0;
    left:80px;
}
#menu li li{
    display:block;
    padding:10px;
}
#menu li li:hover{
    background:#333;
}
```

**jsfiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/ashishanexpert/NaE43/24/

See, no javascript or jQuery required. If you want some animation, then you should use jQuery. Good luck!

Comment: I really appreciate this Ashish Kumar and will look into it but I would just really, really like to get some help with a fixed version of the fiddle that I gave in the description, though I don't even know if my approach is remotely possible of being fixed. Thanks again.

Comment: I's just your fiddle only. I have modified some of your markup and css and as js was not required, so removed that.

Comment: ok, but because there will be a bit of margin between the link and drop down boxes and because of the animations css for me just wouldn't be ideal.

Comment: Margjns and gaps you can change in css only. If about animation, its ur choice.!